# While pressing Allow button for Runtime permission it's not calling action method?

Tags: android, android-studio

in my app  while pressing the allow button  it's  not calling action method once the permission granted after that it's working fine here i'm using fragment for this so how to call action method when allow button pressed any solution.

// variable declaration

```
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 11;
```

// method with onClick listener

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {



                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);


                }
            }
            else {

                CallPErmission();
            }


        }
    });
```

// onrequest permission

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {


        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL:



            if(grantResults.length>0 && permissions[0].equals(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)){

                if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
                {


                    CallPErmission();

                }



           }
```

break;

```
    }


}
```

Comment: Your code looks well for success scenario. Since you're using fragment, is there any chance you have overridden the method `onRequestPermissionsResults` in your activity and forgot to include `super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);`?

Comment: @NabinBhandari super method is written in above code..

Comment: Once try my library: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: @NabinBhandari thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use your fragment `requestPermission` method instead of the `ActivityCompat` one and get the result by overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult` on your fragment?